# vue-chart data is loaded correctly but options are ignored

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

This is driving me nuts.

I have a chart from `vue-chart`, `chartData` is loaded correctly, the chart displays correctly, but `options` are definitely not taken in account, despite setting them statically at the very end on `renderChart` call.

This is using `vue2`/`chartjs 2.9.4`/`vue-chartjs 3.5.1`.

```
<script>
  import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

  const {reactiveProp} = mixins;

  export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    mounted () {
      this.doRenderChart();
    },
    methods: {
      doRenderChart() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, {
          responsive: true,
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: (ctx) => 'My Title'
            },
            tooltip: {
              mode: 'index'
            },
          },
        })
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Most of other similar topics are issues with `{options: {actualoptions}}` object, but here it is not the case.

Maybe a version issue? Using `vue-chart 3.5.1` while other libs are in v2? But the doc doesn't specify anything about this.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using V3 syntax of chart.js while using V2 so that wont work.
In V2 the `title` and `tooltip` config has to be at the root of your options object and `tooltip` has to be renamed to `tooltips`.

For all documentation you can read the V2 config to see where to specify things: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/

Or you can use the migration guide in reverse: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Comment: This helped a lot. Though v2 looks much older than the bright v3.

Comment: It is, but vue-chartjs does not support chart.js v3 so either you will need to stick with v2, find another wrapper or implement chart.js barebone yourself